# Extract Strings between parenthese from String

Tags: java, regex

I am working on my own little Script Language. Now I am stucking at the Script Reader which reads the file and converts it into the Script Parts (variables, functions, if clauses etc). I hava String which saves the Script File content in one line like so:

```
mega = "";test(){hallo();test = "";if(){p2 = -1;}else{p1 = "";}hi = 0;}
```

Now my Problem. I want to get the strings between the parentheses for if clauses and the function (which is around the if clause). I tried it with regex:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(example);
 while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));    
 }
```

But then I get the content between the first parenthese of the function test(){ and the first parenthese that clauses the if clause. How can I extract the Strings between the if clause, else clause and the function?

**EDIT:**

This is want I want to get out after the extraction:

For the If: `p2 = -1;`
For the Else: `p1 = "";`
And for the Function arround:

`hallo();test = "";if(){p2 = -1;}else{p1 = "";}hi = 0;`

**EDIT 2:**
I would like to have it recursive to its endless (when in the if clause is another etc.)

Comment: what outputs you expect to get?

Comment: for the first if: p2 = -1;, else: p1 = ""; and for the function around: hallo();test = "";if(){p2 = -1;}else{p1 = "";}hi = 0;

Comment: you can edit your answer and include this information there :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that regular expressions will not do that. You are looking after correspondent pairs of curly brackets. 
Reminds me of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).